# Calculating number at risk for Kaplan Meier analysis with staggered entry

Tags: r, survival, censoring, kaplan-meier, ggplot2

I am trying to create KM curves in r on data from a telemetry project. The data is right censored and additionally not all individuals were tagged on the same day so they entered the study at different times. I don't think r is calculating the number at risk correctly. Here is my data:

| id | time_start | time_stop | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 90 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 76 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 107 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 9 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 23 | 1 |
| 6 | 0 | 64 | 0 |
| 7 | 0 | 49 | 1 |
| 8 | 0 | 106 | 0 |
| 9 | 19 | 107 | 0 |
| 10 | 2 | 23 | 0 |
| 11 | 2 | 33 | 1 |
| 12 | 0 | 64 | 0 |
| 13 | 0 | 9 | 1 |
| 14 | 37 | 106 | 0 |

At time zero the no. at risk table says 12 individuals but looking at the data only 7 are in the study at time 0. If you add the individuals at risk at time 0 and time 2 then it is equal to 12 so does r just assume since it's such a small difference in days that individuals at time 2 are assumed to be at risk at time 0 as well? I am also confused because it seems to be correctly excluding the individuals that entered much later (day 19 and 37) from the count at time 0, that's why I am not sure if it's calculating incorrectly or I am not understanding the calculation. Here is my code and output for reference :

```
head(telem_juv)


telem_juv_surv <- Surv(time=telem_juv$time_start, time2 = telem_juv$time_stop, telem_juv$status == 1)
summary(telem_juv_surv)

telem_Juvfit <- survfit(Surv(time = time_start, time2 = time_stop, status == 1)  ~ 1 , data = telem_juv)

summary(telem_Juvfit)


telem_juv <- ggsurvplot(
  fit = telem_Juvfit , 
  risk.table = TRUE ,
  xlab= "Days" , 
  ylab= "Overall Survival Probability",
  title = "Captive Reared Telemetry Survival",
)
telem_juv
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to be more of a programming/software problem than a statistics problem. The `survfit()` function only seems to keep track of the number at risk starting from the first event time, which is at `t = 9` in your data, with 12 at risk then. I don't have the code for `ggsurvplot()` handy, but similar code for the `survplot()` function in the `rms` package does the same thing. With delayed-entry counting-process data, It just carries the number at risk at the first event time back to `time = 0`. I don't know if there's a work-around, but that would be off-topic here.

Comment: Assuming this is telemetry for humans, where were the patients who had nonezero entry times before they were in the study?